# Google firebase's firestore rules block key creation/edits

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following firestore rule to allow user access to only their record. It works fine...

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }    
  }
}
```

Now under the users collection, each document contains a field/key name "isAuthenticated" which is set to true from the server side backend using service account persmission.

How can I setup the rules to make sure even the authenticated user cannot update that particular key?

Comment: why track `isAuthenticated` in your database for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disallow all regular users from creating documents:

```
allow create: if false;
```

But note that someone accessing the database with the Admin SDK will still be able to create documents, since they access it with administrative privileges.

**Update*: to prevent the user from updating *any* fields:

```
allow update: if false;
```

To disallow updating a specific field:

```
allow update: if !("isAuthenticated" in request.writeFields);
```

See:

- [Firebase Firestore prevent client side creation of fields in a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335475/firebase-firestore-prevent-client-side-creation-of-fields-in-a-document?rq=1)
- [Allow update on single field in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671227/allow-update-on-single-field-in-firestore)
- [How to check if there is only one specific field who is updated with Firestore rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588621/how-to-check-if-there-is-only-one-specific-field-who-is-updated-with-firestore-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yea but that's the entire document, what about a specific key within a document?

Comment: Thank you. You are a lifesaver. request.writeFields does it.